# How do I extract a value out of a dictionary that contains a value tuple as the key in C#?

Tags: c#, dictionary, valuetuple

The below code snippet initializes a `Dictionary` with a value tuple as key. How do I fetch the individual values after initializing?

```cs
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Dictionary<(int, int), string> dict = new Dictionary<(int, int), string>();

    dict.Add((0, 0), "nul,nul");

    dict.Add((0, 1), "nul,et");

    dict.Add((1, 0), "et,nul");

    dict.Add((1, 1), "et,et");

    for (int row = 0; row <= 1; row++)
    {
        for (int col = 0; col <= 1; col++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Key: {0}, Value: {1}",
                **......Key,
                ......Value);**
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You can index the dict with `dict[(row, col)]`, if that's what you mean.

Comment: `Console.WriteLine(dict.TryGetValue((row, col), out var value) ? $"{row}:{col}:{value}" : $"{row}:{col} value not exists");`

Comment: Thanks  Dmitry Bychenko, that did work :-)

Answer (score 0):

> How do I fetch the individual values...

You have some options:

### 1. Use the [ContainsKey](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.dictionary-2.containskey?view=netcore-3.1) method.

```cs
for (int row = 0; row <= 1; row++)
{
    for (int col = 0; col <= 1; col++)
    {
        if (dict.ContainsKey((row, col)))
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Key: {row} {col}, Value: {dict[(row, col)]}");
        }
        else // key doesn't exist
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Key: {row} {col} doesn't exist");
        }
    }
}
```

### 2. Use the [TryGetValue](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.dictionary-2.trygetvalue?view=netcore-3.1) method.

Per the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.dictionary-2.trygetvalue?view=netcore-3.1), this method is more efficient if the program frequently tries keys that don't exist.

```cs
for (int row = 0; row <= 1; row++)
{
    for (int col = 0; col <= 1; col++)
    {
        if (dict.TryGetValue((row, col), out string value))
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Key: {row} {col}, Value: {value}");
        }
        else // key doesn't exist
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Key: {row} {col} doesn't exist");
        }
    }
}
```

### 3. Use the indexer and catch the [KeyNotFoundException](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.keynotfoundexception?view=netcore-3.1).

This is the [least efficient](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.dictionary-2.containskey?view=netcore-3.1) method.

```cs
for (int row = 0; row <= 1; row++)
{
    for (int col = 0; col <= 1; col++)
    {
        try
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Key: {row} {col}, Value: {dict[(row, col)]}");
        }
        catch (KeyNotFoundException ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"dict does not contain key {row} {col}");
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        }
    }
}
```

You could also use the indexer property without the try/catch block, but since your code doesn't enumerate the dictionary, it could throw an exception, so I don't recommend it.

This leads us to...

### 4. Enumerate the dictionary and use the indexer.

Enumeration could return the keys in any order, which you may or may not want.

```cs
foreach (KeyValuePair<(int, int), string> kvp in dict)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"Key: {kvp.Key.Item1} {kvp.Key.Item2}, Value: {kvp.Value}");
}
```